# PHP assign a value to a variable (globa) from within the classs

Tags: php, variables

I have a small PHP snippet.
How can I assign a new value to my global from within a main class?
Example:

```
$GlobalValue = 0;

class SampleModuleController extends SampleController { 

public function doSomething() {
    $NewValue = 1;
    $GlobalValue = $NewValue
    }
}

echo $GlobalValue;
//This always echo's 0, When I try to output or print outside the class or use somewhere above in the php code. 
//I need to be able to assign the new value from within my class 
//and the function doSomething so it should be 1
```

Comment: I am not a PHP guy, so please take this question/suggestion with caution. Is it possible that you are printing/echoing $GlobalValue before the doSomething function gets executed? Try putting an echo inside doSomething function, that may give you better idea.

Comment: @fluidguid it looks like the initContent function happens after my doSomething function. doSomething() is executed outside the class, so whatever i do there it never gets the value from the initContent. I just need to be able to assign this value from initContent function and be able to access it outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter as reference in the method `doSomething()` and then call that function passing your variable `$GlobalValue`. However it's not very recommended to have global variables. You should consider change your code to more OOP.

```
$GlobalValue = 0;

class SampleModuleController {

    private $newValue = 3;

    public function doSomething(&$variable) {
        $variable = $this->newValue;
    }

}

$ModuleController = new SampleModuleController();
$ModuleController->doSomething($GlobalValue);

echo $GlobalValue; //print 1
```

Comment: Yes I know but I am using another php framework which has tons of functions build in. This works in general but when the php script is initialized i have the value calculated from another public function in the class. How can I set it , instead the hardcoded value of 1? So $variable = $newvariable where $newvariable is initalized from another function inside the same class.

Comment: `$variable = $this->doSomethingOther();` You don't need to declare another variable this way.

Comment: I dont have doSomethingOther() function. The other function is a init function which does not returns anything. Inside it I just get the value. I should try to get/return from it? Sorry but I am new to PHP.

Comment: I edited code. Please change names of variables to your own. You can also create additional function. Everything depends on what are functional requirements of your system which I don't know. I only guess basing on what you posted.

Comment: hi @Tajni thanks four your assistance. $newValue I am getting from another function inside the main SampleModuleController class. So I am not able to set it in doSomething or access it outside the class. When I use global value it always just give me the value of it, it does not take the newly added value. Do you understand my issue?

Comment: So you this another function. Previous example was with another function `$this->doSomethingOther()`. Just use your function instead.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right what you are trying to do can be achieved quite easily with this:

```
global $GlobalValue;
$GlobalValue = 0;

class SampleModuleController {

    public function doSomething() {
        global $GlobalValue;
        $NewValue = 1;
        $GlobalValue = $NewValue;
    }

}

$ModuleController = new SampleModuleController();
$ModuleController->doSomething();

echo $GlobalValue; //print 1
```

They key is in the "global" keyword (which is the same as accessing the $GLOBAL["your_var_name"] container.

Beside this, as others said relying on global variables should be discouraged.

Comment: Yes I've tried with $GLOBAL but no luck. I guess is the framework and the system which makes me a troubles. The issue is that I have one initContent public function where I can only get this value. I than want to be able to access it outside this function and outside this class as @tajni gave his answer above. But everytime I try to assign to the global value and than access it outside it shows the initial value of 0. I don't know why the global value is not updated or changed after this. It is only in the initContent function...

Comment: Are u 100% sure that you have no other place where that global var is updated in any way? maybe its done via $GLOBAL[$varName]? or just in it's simple form accessed with a string key? 
If it's not even that, and u strongly need some tmp value i guess u have to rely on some other system which fits your need (tmp file, db entry, ecc..)
Without knowing the rest of the application it's hard to suggest something else.
Edit: or maybe it's a matter of execution order? so your assign comes after your print? Try to debug it somehow and see what happens to that global var